# Rails rendering file as HTML instead of JS. Using Ransack Gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

Having a nightmare with this one and think i'm going to go crazy. It must be something simple. I have ransack working on my listings#index. It renders the results in a JS partial no problem using remote: true in the search form. All good. however....

I want this same functionality to work on the root_page of the app. So essentially a search bar that will show the search results in a partial just under the bar when a user searches. I can get this to work normally with ransack whereby the page refreshes and the results show from the partial. It will not for the life of me render the partial as JS just like how the listing controller does it.

The code bits are pretty much similar. I'll add them both below. Ransack works, just doesn't recognise the remote: true bit. I've looked into inspect on chrome and can actually see that for some reason the form class doesn't register correctly. I'll screenshot both working and non working bits.

So it's just a matter of the Ransack search query not recognising the remote: true by the looks of it. Any guesses? Does Ransack require something special to be added to the form to enable it to work from a page named home.html.erb? instead of index.html.erb? Would love a set of eyes to literally tell me i'm doing something stupid here. Thanks.

Working code snippets for searching in the listing_controller

listing#index

```
def index
  @search = Listing.ransack(params[:q])
  @data = @search.result(:distinct => true)
  @listings = @data.to_a
end
```

listing index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_or_content_or_aircraft_highlights_or_airframe_engine_apu_weight_or_avionics_connectivity_or_interior_or_exterior_or_additional_info_cont, placeholder: "Search by keyword..", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.submit "Show results", class: "btn btn-secondary btn-lg  btn-block"  %>
<% end %>

<div class="col-md-9" id="aircraft_listing">
  <%= render partial: "shared/aircrafts-list" %>
</div>
```

listing index.js.erb

```
$("#aircraft_listing").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/aircrafts-list' %>");
```

Works like a dream.

Pages controller which won't play ball. Search works but not ajax call

pages#home

```
def home
  @search = Listing.ransack(params[:q])
  if params[:search].present?
    @data = @search.result(:distinct => true)
    @listings = @data.to_a
  end
end
```

pages home.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field: title_or_content_or_aircraft_highlights_or_airframe_engine_apu_weight_or_avionics_connectivity_or_interior_or_exterior_or_additional_info_cont, placeholder: "Search by keyword..", class: "form-control-lg form-control-borderless" %>
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-secondary btn-lg" %>
<% end %>

<div id="home_search_list">
  <%= render partial: "shared/home-search-list" %>
</div>
```

pages home.js.erb

```
$("#home_search_list").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/home-search-list' %>");
alert('Hello Rails');
```

obviously alert doesn't pop up when search ran.

Partials are named (have just checked them again to make sure i'm not going insane)

```
_aircrafts-list.html.erb
_home-search-list.html.erb
```

[image]

[image]

And then the final bit where I can see the remote clearly not happening in the home page version.

[image]

[image]

For some reason the form tag is not appearing in the home page example. I've just noticed this part now after the morning of pulling whats left of my hair out. Fresh eyes would be great. Now one other thing regarding Ransack, The fact my routes have resources for listing but i literally have just the root_path connected to my pages controller home action, does this matter with Ransack?

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using the same layout for both of these HTML files? I'm only asking because if jquery_ujs (from application.js) isn't included, then `remote: true` won't do anything.

Comment: Hi Veridian, I am using the same layout actually. Had to double check that earlier. I've actually just solved this right now. I'm a pleb, and knew I was but the process of actually writing out the problem helped. 

I'm doing this along with another developer(front end) so I only noticed the search form for was already nested in a form tag so made the Ransack and remote:true call  redundant. when I realised this I got to see the call coming in. Noticed it was still trying to render listings controller references so changed the variable and added the url path to the form to solve it.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks for your time reading my question. Sorry if it was a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

So apologies all. I actually figured this out. See comments. Was already a reference to form tag so it made the Ransack form call redundant (Doing this with another developer so didn't notice the form tag above in the pages code. Silly stuff by me). When I removed this style I could see the remote call working. However it was still calling the data from the listings controller. I just needed to change the variable to something else @q and then also added the url path option to the form like below. Thanks everyone for reading. Apologies for the waste of time. Sometimes it just takes writing the whole thing down to realise how stupid you're being. Suppose can be used as a reference for other people going forward.

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: root_path, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Allowed me to reference the root_path with the Ransack functionality.